# Sharing software made for Ubuntu

Tags: ppa

I've created my first program, and made a PPA. How can I advertise this program in Ubuntu? Is there any way?

Comment: as far as I know .Ubuntu isnt an advertising platform ... you advertise by finding a website that deals with your type of program. such as if you had an editor app you would advertise it on pages that have to deal with editors. I have found all my ppa's from sites where people talk about an app and through searching google

Comment: Are you trying to sell your application or make it part of the free software available? Your posting needs to be made clearer. Edit your question rather than replying to clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options when it comes to advertising your software to get it known to the community. To name a few:

- Find forums which are in the niche your software fills and addresses and post there about it.
- Get it known via Twitter or Facebook if you have actually an audience which is likely to re-tweet or promote your post.
- Send the major blogs of the Ubuntu world a hint about your software, if they like it and find it useful they most likely write an article about it.
- If it is a game you made you might want to consider places like itch.io to put your game up.

The Linux community is big, so don't be surprised if someone already made a similar tool/program/game already but this above should give you a good start on where and how to get your program known.